# Simple replace across an array fails - unexpected output

Tags: regex, powershell

suppose I have an array and I want to bracket each of its elements.  I would expect the following would do it:

```
"a b c d".split() -replace ".*", "<$&>"
```

however the output I get is:

```
<a><>
<b><>
<c><>
<d><>
```

instead of:

```
<a>
<b>
<c>
<d>
```

and I can't figure out why.  what's going on with this?

Comment: thanks for finding the answer.  it's counter-intuitive but I get it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think it happens because you used `.*` as a pattern - the parser also treats null string as matches and that's why you get the extra matches. You can fix it by using the pattern:

```
^.*
```

which will force the matches to start from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Or he can use ".+", as indicated in the post @briantist linked too